# How to get stored items in localStorage from an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage, map-function

I have a simple shopping cart that I stored in localStorage using a map function which was suggested by online resource but now I don't know how to get those items from localStorage and add it on a variable. sorry if that was easy for you guys but I'm new in programming.

```
function additemtocard(title, price, imgsrc) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('each-cart-row');
    let mainElement = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-layout')[0];
    let carttitle = mainElement.querySelectorAll('.title');
    for(let i = 0; i < carttitle.length; i++){
        if(carttitle[i].innerText == title){
            alert('this item is on the cart');
        return;
        };
    }
    let tag = '<h4 class="title">'+(title)+'</h4><span class="price">'+(price)+'</span><h5 class="qty">1</h5><button class="removebtn">remove</button>';
    let cartlayout = document.querySelector('.added-product');
    div.innerHTML = tag;
    cartlayout.appendChild(div); 
    div.querySelectorAll('.removebtn')[0].addEventListener('click', removebtncart);      
}


function savecart(){
    let qty = document.querySelector('.totalqty').textContent;
    let tprice = document.querySelector('.total-layout span').textContent;
    let listitem = document.querySelectorAll('.each-cart-row');
    let m = [...listitem].map(function(item) {
      return {
        text: item.querySelector('.title').textContent.trim(),
        price: item.querySelector('.price').textContent.trim(),
      }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('qty', qty);
    localStorage.setItem('tprice', tprice);
    localStorage.setItem('layoutlist', JSON.stringify(m));
}


function loadcart() {
    let qty = localStorage.getItem('qty');
    let tprice = localStorage.getItem('tprice');
    let m = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layoutlist'));
    document.querySelector('.totalqty').textContent = qty;
    document.querySelector('.total-layout span').textContent = tprice;

    // i need to get title & price from m variable and add it to below code
    document.querySelector('.title').textContent;
    document.querySelector('.price').textContent; 

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="cart-layout">
   <div class="added-product">
    <!-- Div with each-cart-row class should be added here each time button is clicked -->
   </div>
   <div class="total-layout">
       <h2>Total</h2>
       <span>$0</span>
   </div>
   <div class="added-cart-btn">
       <button id="removeall">Remove all</button>
       <button>Proceed</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `m` should be an array. Loop over the array an get the title and price from the items in the array `m.forEach(item =>  console.log(item.text, item.price));`

Comment: And since `JSON.parse()` can throw a SyntaxError exception, I would wrap that in a try/catch an use an empty array as the default value for `m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate through the items

```
function loadcart() {
    let qty = localStorage.getItem('qty');
    let tprice = localStorage.getItem('tprice');
    let m = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layoutlist'));
    document.querySelector('.totalqty').textContent = qty;
    document.querySelector('.total-layout span').textContent = tprice;

// i need to get title & price from m variable and add it to below code

for(let item of m) { 
  document.querySelector('.title').textContent = item.text;
  document.querySelector('.price').textContent = item.price;
  }
}
```

Comment: zfrisch - I tried your code and when i console log.  it shows me the text but it doesn't exist in the cart. am I doing something wrong

Comment: @KinanAlamdar It might be down to your selector. You're consistently changing the same elements(`'.title'` and `'.price'`) over and over. If you're trying to append to them you might use `+=` instead of `=`, or if you're trying to adjust to specific items and prices you're going to want to figure out where they are in your markup.

Comment: zfrisch - i have added an HTML code can you please see if you can help.

Comment: @KinanAlamdar your markup doesn't help. The elements need to exist in order for them to to have text displayed. If they don't exist you should make them, but that's out of the scope of this question.